# How do I properly allow anonymous authentication with MongoDB Realm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, realm

I'm trying to use MongoDB Realm in my web app. Basically it will store the input from a form I have as a component of this web app. I have enabled anonymous authentication for my Realm app. However, when I try to employ this, I am having ID errors. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Here is my error and code snippet.

Error:

```
×
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
App.addTodo
src/Stitch2.js:181
  178 | this.db
  179 |   .collection("item")
  180 |   .insertOne({
> 181 |     owner_id: this.client.auth.user.id,
      | ^  182 |     // // id: this.client.auth.user.id, 
  183 |     // item: value
  184 |   })
```

Code Snippet:

```
addTodo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value } = this.state;
    // insert the todo into the remote Stitch DB
    // then re-query the DB and display the new todos

    this.db
      .collection("item")
      .insertOne({
        owner_id: this.client.auth.user.id,
        item: value
      })
      .then(this.displayTodos)
      .catch(console.error);
  }
```

Comment: Since you're asking how to *properly allow anonymous authentication* it would probably be a good idea to include your authentication code in the question. See [Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/#define-the-authprovider) and then please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)